# Align div to bottom of Bootstrap4 card-body

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstraps cards. I have card-header and card-footer and they are working great. In the card-body I have a card-title. This title can take up 1 or 2 lines in the card-body. Also inside this card-body I have some information in a div. I want to align this informational div to the card-body bottom as I use row/col to align things nicely but because 1 card-title is 1 line and another is 2 lines when you look across cards in the page this additional information doesn't line up exactly between cards and bottom aligning would solve that I think.

So basically I want the orangered divs to line up at the bottom of their cards because then visually across cards they would look to line up.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  .box:hover {
    /*-webkit-transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);
    transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
</style>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="box" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

          <!-- CARD HEADER -->
          <div class="card-header" style="margin: 0px;">
Header Stuff
          </div>

          <!-- CARD BODY -->
          <div class="card-body" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h6 class="card-title">This is a 1 line title</h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="d-flex align-items-center">-->
            <div class="container" style="background-color: orangered">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Starts On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  1/1/2019
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Ends On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  12/31/2019
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  #:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  52
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
          </div>

          <!-- CARD FOOTER -->
          <div class="card-footer">
Footer stuff
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

          <!-- CARD HEADER -->
          <div class="card-header" style="margin: 0px;">
            Header stuff
          </div>

          <!-- CARD BODY -->
          <div class="card-body" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h6 class="card-title">This is a longer description that will span 2 rows making things not line up right between cards</h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="d-flex align-items-center">-->
            <div class="container" style="background-color: orangered">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Starts On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  1/1/2020
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Ends On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  12/31/2020
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  #:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  10
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
          </div>

          <!-- CARD FOOTER -->
          <div class="card-footer">
Footer stuff here
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few things:

- added `position:absolute` with some (24%) clearance from the bottom;
- the `container` class implemented a width of 100%, which is why the box now went outside the boundary;
- `card-body` class implemented a 20px padding
- To get the exact styling, we removed the width 20px from the 100% width (from the cowntainer)

**complete snippet** below:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 340px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box:hover {
  /*-webkit-transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);
    transform: scale(1.10, 1.10);*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.orangeRedClass {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 24%;
  width: calc(100% - 40px) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="box" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

          <!-- CARD HEADER -->
          <div class="card-header" style="margin: 0px;">
            Header Stuff
          </div>

          <!-- CARD BODY -->
          <div class="card-body" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h6 class="card-title">This is a 1 line title</h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="d-flex align-items-center">-->
            <div class="container orangeRedClass" style="background-color: orangered">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Starts On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  1/1/2019
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Ends On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  12/31/2019
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  #:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  52
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
          </div>

          <!-- CARD FOOTER -->
          <div class="card-footer">
            Footer stuff
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="box" style="margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

          <!-- CARD HEADER -->
          <div class="card-header" style="margin: 0px;">
            Header stuff
          </div>

          <!-- CARD BODY -->
          <div class="card-body" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <h6 class="card-title">This is a longer description that will span 2 rows making things not line up right between cards</h6>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!--<div class="d-flex align-items-center">-->
            <div class="container orangeRedClass" style="background-color: orangered">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Starts On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  1/1/2020
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  Ends On:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  12/31/2020
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  #:
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  10
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
          </div>

          <!-- CARD FOOTER -->
          <div class="card-footer">
            Footer stuff here
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```